# Startup shell doen't work on Unbuntu WS2(Windows)

Tags: shell, ubuntu, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently used Ubuntu18 running on WSL2 windows. I am going to write a shell to start all services rapitally, But the error always present:

```
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

My Shell script(start.sh) is:

```
#!/bin/sh
service docker start
docker start <container_id>
echo "The container has been started"
```

and then run

```
sudo ./start.sh
```

Comment: Does the socket `/var/run/docker.sock` exist? Does it work if you run the commands one by one instead of through the script?

Comment: Yes, One by one will work.. :)   @Panki

Comment: I believe `service docker start` might run async. Try placing a `sleep` after it.

Comment: Yes , I think sleep should resolve that ....